# Why do I get an error when installing my Pebble app on the aplite emulator?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm having a hard time trying to install my Pebble app to the aplite emulator. I'm using the Mac SDK, not CloudPebble, and when I type:

```
pebble install --emulator aplite --debug
```

I get the following output:

```
[DEBUG   ] Initializing reader thread
[DEBUG   ] Reader thread loaded on tid Thread-1
[DEBUG   ] Phone ==> Watch: 000d000b035590fef60078055554432b32
[DEBUG   ] Phone ==> Watch: 0001001000
[DEBUG   ] Watch ==> Phone: 00960010015553bdef76322e392d71656d75352d362d67663761343430350000000000000000000000663761343430350000fe0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005553bdef00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026658a035553bdef656e5f55530000015858585858585800
[DEBUG   ] Phone ==> Watch: 00111770025ce319237d734d77af654e024035e51e
[DEBUG   ] Watch ==> Phone: 00960010015553bdef76322e392d71656d75352d362d67663761343430350000000000000000000000663761343430350000fe0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005553bdef00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026658a035553bdef656e5f55530000015858585858585800
[DEBUG   ] Status: '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
[DEBUG   ] WS Operation failed with response 16777216
[ERROR   ] Failed to install 'build/xxx-xxx.pbw'
[DEBUG   ] Phone info: 'pypkjs,0.0.0,qemu'
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 209.118.208.39
[DEBUG   ] Analytics collection disabled due to lack of internet connectivity
```

Any idea what goes wrong?

I don't have such problems with the `basalt` emulator.

**UPDATE** After running `pebble wipe` and `pebble login`, I'm getting slightly different message:

```
[DEBUG   ] Phone ==> Watch: 00020031ff02
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): timeline-sync.getpebble.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/runner/websocket.py", line 173, in go_do_install
self.pebble.pebble.install_app_pebble_protocol(f.name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 1186, in install_app_pebble_protocol
[DEBUG   ] Status: '\x00\x00\x00\x01'
watch_fw_version = self.get_watch_fw_version()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 662, in get_watch_fw_version
self.get_watch_version_info()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 645, in get_watch_version_info
version_info = self.get_versions()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 920, in get_versions
return EndpointSync(self, "VERSION").get_data()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0-beta12/Pebble/common/phonesim/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 504, in get_data
raise PebbleError(None, "Timed out... Is the Pebble phone app connected/direct BT connection up?")
PebbleError: Timed out... Is the Pebble phone app connected/direct BT connection up? (ID:None) <Greenlet at 0x109490e10: go_do_install> failed with PebbleError

[DEBUG   ] WS Operation failed with response 16777216
[ERROR   ] Failed to install 'build/statium-pebble.pbw'
```

Comment: Note: this post is potentially a bug specific to `Pebble SDK 3.0beta12` (and below, the user reports using `Pebble SDK 3.1` with the emulator command `pebble wipe` resolved the issue). **As of 2021 the current release is** `Pebble SDK 4.3`, officially found here: https://developer.rebble.io/developer.pebble.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic error that happens every once and a while on aplite. This is going to be fixed in 3.1 of the commandline SDK.

You can run `pebble wipe` and `pebble login` to resolve the issue until the official fix comes in 3.1.

Comment: Didn't help. Getting a more detailed error though. cf. updated question.

Comment: I just upgraded to the SDK 3.1 (I was 3.0beta12) and now things work. Maybe the wipe was responsible after all. :)